# How can i create some adding fields on django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a class, a form thats is about a Person. All the information about the person(name, identification, contact), but i also, need information about the family of that person, the name of the family members etc.... I wanna do this in a way that the user can add a family member one by one, because some persons could have 2 family members and others 4.. or 10.
And i wanna do this automatically, in the form of the person the user should be able to fill the information of the person and add the family members...

Comment: Try inline formsets.  This is a good tutorial: https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing in your Person model add one field:

```
familyMembers = IntegerField(default=None,blank=True, null=True)
```

and in your model form you can use this field to allow user to insert no. of family members.

```
familyMembers =forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={}))
```